# Single Photon Detection in a Moving Train of Detectors Setup

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, wave-particle-duality

I’ve been pondering a thought experiment related to quantum mechanics and photon detection, and I’m curious about the theoretical outcome and whether any similar experiments have been conducted.

Imagine we have two setups designed to detect single photons emitted from a laser that’s been attenuated to ensure, on average, the emission of one photon per minute. In the first setup, a single photon detector is placed stationary in front of the laser beam, effectively detecting a photon approximately once per minute.

In the second setup, we replace the single detector with an infinitely long train of photon detectors. These detectors move across the laser beam such that each detector is in front of the beam for only one second before the next detector takes its place, ensuring there’s always a detector in front of the beam. Given the laser’s emission rate, would the probability of detection in this second setup still result in one detection per minute, considering each detector’s brief exposure time?

Here are my specific questions:

1. How does the moving train of photon detectors setup affect the probability of detecting a photon, considering the quantum nature of photon emission and the instantaneous detection principle?
2. Are there any practical experiments or theoretical frameworks that closely resemble this setup, especially those exploring single photon detection, quantum mechanics principles, or the statistical nature of quantum events?
3. Could the brief exposure of each detector to the photon’s potential path influence the overall detection rate, or is the detection probability purely a function of the photon emission rate and the quantum mechanics of photon-detector interaction?

I’m particularly interested in understanding how quantum mechanics principles apply to this scenario and whether the duration a detector is exposed to the potential photon path plays a role in the probability of photon detection.

Comment: There is essentially no difference between the two scenarios. Like all detectors, the stationary detector has a finite response time that sets an intrinsic time scale. Usually when measurements of photons are discussed it is tacitly assumed that the technical specifications of the detector is selected in such a way that the detection probability is optimal.